# Diferença entre o Alter Table Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, terminologia

Gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre a execução nas cláusulas `Alter Table` quando se insere o `ADD CONSTRAINT` , como por exemplo executando o seguinte código:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

Qual a diferença em utilizar esse código:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

Há melhorias na performance, segurança, ou alguma informação que é importante saber quando se trata de banco de dados?
E aproveitando a pergunta,
 exatamente o que faz o `ADD CONSTRAINT`?(Atualmente utilizo `MySQL`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ADD CONSTRAINT** -> Para permitir a nomeação de uma restrição FOREIGN KEY e para definir uma restrição FOREIGN KEY em várias colunas.

- A diferença seria no nome da restrição criada, no primeiro caso seria adicionado um nome default aleatório, exemplo (FK__Orders__PersonID__1E2636F2), já no segundo caso será criado com nome(FK_PersonOrder), sendo possível ser acessado e alterado por algum sistema, sabendo o nome da FK.

Answer (score 5):

A adição do `ADD CONSTRAINT` é utilizada para definir o nome da `FOREIGN KEY` e para criar chave estrangeiras com múltiplas colunas.

[mais informações](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)